# How to fetch name field for a record of given record id but known object?

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql, object

I am trying to obtain all related child (look up) records of a record whose record id is passed. Salesforce docs say that for every object, regardless of type, name is a standard field, just like Id.

However,

```
select name, id from case
```

throws the error

> No such column name on entity case

Similar error is thrown for several objects other than `Case` when name (which is apparently a standard field for every object) is tried to be fetched.

So how does one fetch name field for a record of known record id and object type (which is easily obtained from record id)?

Comment: Case does not have a standard field called `Name`, it's `CaseNumber`. The same goes for Task or some other objects. 
I would say Use a dynamic SOQL in this case or put conditions based on the object you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce says, sometimes it is not accurate, what it says :)

There is a possibility to get "main" name field for every object: custom and standard. Use [isNameField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_isNameField) method.

```
String objectApiName = 'Case';
for(SObjectField field :((SObject)Type.forName(null, objectApiName).newInstance()).getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()){
    DescribeFieldResult describe  = field.getDescribe();
    if(describe.isNameField()){
        System.debug('Name field: ' + describe.getName());
    }
}
```

For `Case` object it is to debug as:

> DEBUG|Name field: CaseNumber

For `WorkOrder`:

> DEBUG|Name field: WorkOrderNumber

For `Task`

> DEBUG|Name field: Subject

For normal `Account`

> DEBUG|Name field: Name

For `Lead`

> DEBUG|Name field: Name

---

The same information is available via REST API [Get Object Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_object_info.htm), or from LWC  [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_object_info). Check `nameFields` in a response.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the detailed answer!